# Issue loading shared library

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a shared library and application in same folder and when I try to open `terminal` from that folder and run the application it gives library not found issue. If i set environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then it works well

My question is:

Wouldnt opening the terminal from that folder sets environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Could you give more detail on how you got the two files?

Comment: i set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to current folder and it works

Answer (score 2):

> Wouldnt opening the terminal from that folder sets environment variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

No, you will have to add it to your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Basically the shared library's location is not in the linker's search path. You will have to either

1. modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and then run ldd again or
2. move the shared library file to one of the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`already present

Comment: Adding to this, if you want to set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH automatically when terminal starts, then set the env variable in ~/.bashrc